# Chinese language support visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, cjk

I've inherited a C# application developed in Visual Studio 2013. Some of the developers are in China. They are still using VS 2013, and can't upgrade. Some of the comments and text constants in the code are in Chinese, and I have to maintain the proper encoding. Unfortunately, my version seems to be changing the characters to weird ascii stuff. Does anyone know where I can get Chinese language support for my installation of VS 2013? How do I fix this on my end?

Comment: It sounds like it's not opening the file with the correct character encoding.  Do you know what that "proper encoding" is?  You could try [specifying that encoding manually when opening a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding), though I'm not sure how you'd force that encoding permanently for the project.

Comment: That could be close to what I need. But what's happening is that I build the project, and the result executable contains the bad ascii codes rather than the original Chinese, even if I don't open the file in Visual Studio. Maybe it gets messed up when I download from source control?

Comment: "executable contains the bad ascii codes".. so this would be the text constants and not the comments.. Have you looked at the chars in a hex editor both before and after compilation?  You need to figure out .. either they were SWITCHED during some process like "GetEncoding()".. OR.. The correct codepage is not being used to display them.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923876/why-are-my-chinese-characters-not-displayed-correctly-in-c-sharp-string) for a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I may be misunderstanding the post you linked. The problem is in the actual c# code files, not in data stored in a SQL table. Yes, it may well be a problem with codepage. I'll examine that post carefully and see if it helps.